# Find and replace strange symbols in my table

Tags: mysql, replace

I am finding weird symbols appearing as a result of an import which went well apart from strange symbols.

I am trying to find all references to

```
‚Äì
```

I would like it replaced with

`'`

This is what i tried, that failed:

```
update exp_channel_data set * = replace(*,'‚Äì',''');
```

Comment: Would repeating the import with the proper settings not be a better idea?

Comment: @Pekka - seconded, far and away the better option!

Comment: Make sure that the charset of your table/database matches the charset of the original.

Comment: Ahhh i see, that might not be possible as its a fresh install of a CMS and the other one is ancient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update table_name set field_name = replace(field_name,'‚Äì',''');
```

Is the correct way to do it like you have sort of said above.

However, if you have only just imported, and not used any of the data yet, you would be better off just re-importing the data and changing the import settings to ensure the correct character set to get rid of the anomaly.

If you can run a php script, something like the following should work:
It's not native SQL but it does automate the process. It does all tables and all fields. Obviously if you only want one table etc you can just alter the script (remove outer loop)

```
// Assuming you have connected to database
$dbname = "your_db"
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$tresult = mysql_query($sql);
while ($trow = mysql_fetch_row($tresult)) {
    $fresult = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM {$trow[0]}");
    if (mysql_num_rows($fresult) > 0) {
        while ($frow = mysql_fetch_assoc($fresult)) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE {$trow[0]} set {$frow['Field']} = replace({$frow['Field']},'‚Äì',''');");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No worries, I have had the same problem before! Sometime a little script saves a whole load of import symbol pain :)